# Sign-In with Google "Access blocked: This app's request is invalid"

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, next-auth

I am trying to add user authentication with next-auth.js through firebase. I followed the documentation on how to implement a sign in system using google as a provider. Even though I entered in the right credentials, google is still saying that the app's request is invalid.

Here is how I am making the request:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
   // Configure one or more authentication providers
   providers: [
      GoogleProvider({
         clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
         clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      }),
      // ...add more providers here
   ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just mention the Authorized redirect URIs in your OAuth 2.0 Client ID configuration (image attached):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cI8b.png)

next auth doc also state to mention the : Authorized redirect URIs

For production: https://{YOUR_DOMAIN}/api/auth/callback/google
For development: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google

doc link : https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google

Comment: I did exactly same, I still get same error. Please have a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651120/next-auth-google-provider-doesnt-work-at-access-blocked-this-app-s-request-is