# next-auth google provider doesn't work at, Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, next.js, next-auth

I have been hitting my head on this whole week. I have tried literally everything. I am trying to use next-auth + google provider.

In GCP, in authoried urls and redirect urls:
localhost:3000
realdomain.com

localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
realdomain.com/api/auth/callback/google

[...nextauth].js:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return session;
    },
  },
})
```

NEXTAUTH_URL=realdomain.com

with above config it worked locally. But in production, it always redirected to localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google and not worked. So, I removed all the locals domain in GCP, still doesn't work. One thing to note:
when I console.log(providers)
even in production app it is:

```
google: Object { id: "google", name: "Google", type: "oauth", … }
​​
callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google"
​​
id: "google"
​​
name: "Google"
​​
signinUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/google"
​​
type: "oauth"
```

still localhost.
The error:

```
Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
```

"next-auth": "^4.20.1"

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change the value of the
`NEXTAUTH_URL` environmental variable from localhost to your real domain
i.e:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://yourRealDomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me:

step1:

[image]

step2:

[image]

step3:

[image]

Comment: please [edit] your answer and replace the "stepx:" by a short description of what should be done

Answer (score 0):

It worked to me using these values:

*.env file*

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/auth

*Google console - allowed redirect URI:*

http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/auth/callback/google